# Is there a way to find out what dlls i need to run my App?

Tags: c#, windows, installation

I am working on a Console application in C#, which i want to upload on GitHub

Currently when trying to run my Program they have to install the entire SDK.
I want it, so that when people Download the App, they dont have to install the entire SDK for the app they will only use once then probably uninstall.

Now my Idea is to include all the dlls that are needed for the Program to run in the download
Is there a way to find out what dlls i need to run my App?
or is there a better way to solve this Problem?

Comment: It's not the SDK, it's the .Net _runtime_. What version of the runtime are you targeting?

Comment: oh i see its the .NET 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Other way to include the runtime dlls that you require, and your own code and dependencies, is you use the option to deploy a single file application.

You need to adjust the project file such as this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But to understand fully and decide exactly how you want to do this then I suggest reading the MS article here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli

This can explain better than I can!